# Django rest framework remove a field from API Create form

Tags: django, python-3.x, api, django-rest-framework

I have a model and viewset related to this model,
here is my code :

```
class EMAILTemplate(models.Model):
    """ Message SMS Template """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField()
    tokens = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.tokens = ",".join(re.findall(r'{{\s*(.*?)\s*}}', self.body))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I don't want field tokens to be in my create form in Django rest framework create or edit form, because as you see It's going to be extracted from body field.
but I want to have this field in view single model or list of models.

and here is my ModelSerializer :

```
class EmailTemplateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EMAILTemplate
        fields = ('name', 'body', 'user', 'tokens')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify `tokens` as read only field:

```
class EmailTemplateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EMAILTemplate
        fields = ('name', 'body', 'user', 'tokens')
        read_only_fields = ('tokens',)
```

Comment: when I do so, my tokens field isn't filled as I expected.
my tokens field should be extracted from body field.
when I don't put the line you mentioned, the token field appears in form and whatever I fill in this input, In database It gets filled with value I expected.

for example if my body is "I am {{first_name}} {{last_name}} and I am {{age}} years old." the token field value should be : "first_name, last_name, age"

Comment: @mhndev This answer will work as is. Because you are *generating the `tokens`* in **`save()`** method.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite the current `to_representation` method

```
class EmailTemplateSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        try:
            if self.context['view'].action in ['list', 'detail']:
                # get the original representation
                ret = super(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
                # remove 'tokens' field
                ret.pop('tokens')
                return ret
        except KeyError:
            return super(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
        return super(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer, self).to_representation(obj)
```

Comment: when I do as you said, not only the field token still appears in in rest framework create form, but also in list action I get null objects instead of actual json objects.